# MongoDB - How to migrate LUUID to UUID?

Tags: mongodb, uuid

How can I change all existing documents LUUID properties to UUID?

My collection looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : LUUID("70094955-9989-49bf-8261-6d32f46a2040"),
    "metadata" : {
        "userUuid" : LUUID("827ac2d6-2c49-40c4-9437-e7c2e41f983e"),
    },
}
```

I want to convert all documents with _id and metadata.userUuid LUUID to UUID. So, after migration documents need to look like:

```
{
    "_id" : UUID("70094955-9989-49bf-8261-6d32f46a2040"),
    "metadata" : {
        "userUuid" : UUID("827ac2d6-2c49-40c4-9437-e7c2e41f983e"),
    },
}
```

Some documents have already been changed manually. Mongo query cannot "brake" already migrated documents.

How to do this? MongoDB v4.4